# incomplete gamma function in R (conditional mean of Weibull to the power of N)

Tags: r, gamma-distribution, conditional-expectation, weibull-distribution

I am trying to calculate:

$$
E(w^n | \underline{w} < w < \bar{w})
$$

where $w$ follows a 2 parameter Weibull distribution $w \sim W(\lambda,k)$

From a previous [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/462150/conditional-mean-of-weibull-to-the-power-of-n/462163#462163), I know the following formula for the expected value:

$$
E(w^n | \underline{w} < w < \bar{w}) = \lambda^n \frac{\gamma(n/k+1,\bar{w}^{k/n})- \gamma(n/k+1,\underline{w}^{k/n})}{exp(-\underline{w}^{k/n}\lambda^{-k}) -exp(-\bar{w}^{k/n}\lambda^{-k}) } 
$$

But I'm trying to simulate this in R using the `gammainc` function and I'm getting a strange result. Consider the following variables:

```
w_u<-15
w_l<-4
shape<-3
scale<-8
```

We know $E(w^n)=\lambda^n\Gamma(1+\frac{n}{k})$

For $n=3$

`scale^n*gamma(1+n/shape)` = 512

Now, to calculate the conditional expectation I do:

```
n<-3
upterm1<- gammainc((w_u^(shape/n))*(scale^(-shape)),(n/shape)+1)[1]
upterm2<- gammainc((w_l^(shape/n))*(scale^(-shape)),(n/shape)+1)[1]
lowterm<- exp((-w_l^{shape/n})*scale^{-shape})-exp((-w_u^{shape/n})*scale^{-shape})

expected_wind_speed_n_cond<-(scale^n)*(upterm1-upterm2)/lowterm
```

Which returns a value close to 8.5, which does not make much sense, given the boundaries for $w$. Note that in R, the `gammainc` function seem to [input](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/expint/versions/0.1-6/topics/gammainc) parameters the other way around it is typically [noted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

I get similar results when using:

```
upterm1<-pgamma(wr^(shape/n)*(scale^(-shape)),n/shape+1)*gamma(n/shape+1)
upterm2<-pgamma(win^(shape/n)*(scale^(-shape)),n/shape+1)*gamma(n/shape+1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Abramowitz & Stegun didn't get the order of the arguments wrong, they got the upper vs lower tail wrong. That is, the first argument is the exponent on $t$ in the integral and the second is  the limit of integration, both in the R package following Abramowitz & Stegun and in Wikipedia, but the sources disagree about  whether you get the integral from 0 to $x$ or $x$ to  $\infty$. Your  code seems to have swapped the argument order but not swapped which tail you're using.

Comment: @ThomasLumley: that sounds like the beginning of a good answer. Do you have the time and inclination to fill in a few details and post it?

Comment: Your snippet "`scale^3*shape(1+3/k)` = 457.2" does not compute. Do you mean `nn <- 3; scale^nn*gamma(1+nn/scale)` (which in my R console yields a slightly different result, 455.12)?

Comment: What is `gammainc` supposed to do?  This function is not part of base `R`.  Base `R` does supply a (standardized) incomplete gamma function: it is called `pgamma`.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, my bad. fixed a typo. it's ```scale^n*gamma(1+n/shape)``` which gives 512.

Comment: @ThomasLumley, thank you. I think that I got it correct when using [1] at the end of the expression. ```gammainc``` returns a list with the lower, upper and the regularized incomplete gamma functions. The first element of that list is the lower incomplete gamma function.

Comment: @whuber, thank you. It is part of the ```pracma``` package. I've used ```pgamma``` and get similar results.

Answer (score 1):

I'll use a slightly different form for the conditional expectation of a Weibull random variable: $$E[W \ | \ a<W<b]=\frac{\lambda \Gamma \left( \frac{1}{k}+1 \right) \left[ P \left( \frac{1}{k}+1,\left(\frac{b}{\lambda} \right)^k \right) - P \left( \frac{1}{k}+1,\left(\frac{a}{\lambda} \right)^k \right) \right] }{e^{-\left( a / \lambda \right)^k}-e^{- \left( b / \lambda \right)^k}} \ ,$$ where the lower incomplete gamma function $P \left( \alpha,x \right)$ is the cumulative distribution function of a normalized gamma (scale=1) random variable defined as $$P \left( \alpha,x \right)=\frac{1}{\Gamma \left( \alpha \right) } \int_0^x t^{\alpha-1} e^{-t}dt $$

Based on whuber's demonstration in the linked question from the poster, we know that $W^3$ is also Weibull, with a shape parameter of $k/3$ and a scale parameter of $\lambda^3$. Using the lower and upper limiting points given above, we have

$$E[W^3 \ | \ 4^3 < W^3 < 15^3]=\frac{\lambda^3 \Gamma \left( \frac{3}{k}+1 \right) \left[ P \left( \frac{3}{k}+1,\left(\frac{15^3}{\lambda^3} \right)^{k/3} \right) - P \left( \frac{3}{k}+1,\left(\frac{4^3}{\lambda^3} \right)^{k/3} \right) \right] }{e^{-\left( 4^3 / \lambda^3 \right)^{k/3}}- \ e^{- \left( 15^3 / \lambda^3 \right)^{k/3}}} \ $$

In R, using the pgamma function, we get

```
k <- 3
lambda <- 8
n <- 3

w_l <- 4
w_u <- 15

p_u <- pgamma((w_u^n/lambda^n)^(k/n),shape=n/k+1,scale=1)
p_l <- pgamma((w_l^n/lambda^n)^(k/n),shape=n/k+1,scale=1)

exp_l <- exp(-(w_l^n/lambda^n)^(k/n))
exp_u <- exp(-(w_u^n/lambda^n)^(k/n))

answer <- (lambda^n*gamma(n/k+1)*(p_u-p_l))/(exp_l-exp_u)

answer 
[1] 570.846
```

Here is simulation code to confirm:

```
unifs <- runif(30000000)
w3 <- lambda^n*(-log(exp(-(w_l^n/lambda^n)^(n/k))*(1-unifs)+unifs*(exp(-(w_u^n/lambda^n)^(n/k))))^(n/k))

mean(w3)
[1] 570.8276
```

Comment: The incomplete gamma function you mentioned, is it upper incomplete gamma or lower incomplete gamma? Because as per my knowledge the function looks like lower incomplete gamma

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've made the correction.